# How to receive react native push notification in foreground and background

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-push-notification

Im using
React Native Push Notification https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification
Currently, it will receive push notification after closing the app.

1. How can I pass my pushMessage(chat) into the notification?
2. How to make it receive push notification in foreground (when the app still open) and background (without opening the app)  *currently it will receive the notification after closing the app

which part should I work on?

```
App.js
--------
PushNotification.configure({
    // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
    onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );

        // process the notification . * this will overwrite the My Notification 1 below
        PushNotification.localNotification({
            foreground: true,
            title: "My Notification Title",
            message: "My Notification 2", // (required)
        });

        // required on iOS only (see fetchCompletionHandler docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html)
        notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
    },


});


class App extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        const connection = signalr.hubConnection('https://api.abc.com');
        const proxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');

        proxy.on('pushMessage', (chat) => {
            PushNotification.localNotification({
               foreground: true,
               title: "My Notification Title",
               message: "My Notification 1", // (required)
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: iOS requires you to handle notifications yourself when your app is in the foreground. Is your onNotification function being called when your app receives a notification and it's in the foreground?

Comment: @MattyK14 so for this package, android is it able to push notification in the foreground? only iOS cant

Comment: I'm not completely sure for Android but I believe notifications behave the same way.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to identify a solution to this problem? I am facing same problem.

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. Any solution?

Comment: Me too facing same problem ? Any solution?